# How do I use jQuery to activate a function only when a condition is met?

Tags: css, javascript, jquery

I want to activate a jQuery function only if the width of my screen is between an x value and a y value. I tried this:

```
$(function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth
    if (770 < width < 995 ) {
        $(function(){
            var altezza = $(".modello").innerHeight();
            $(".modellato").css('min-height',altezza);
        });
    }
});
```

But it didn't work. How can I get that to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im replying because there are multiple factors which can be improved, which require a post:

```
$(function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth
    if( width > 770 && width < 995 ){
        $(".modellato").css('min-height', $(".modello").innerHeight());
    }
});
```

- The if-statement is **very basic programming**
- You don't need the `$(function(){` inside the `if`, the code will run perfectly fine like this
- if you use the innerheight of `.modello` just once, you can use the value itself in the `.css()`

Comment: jQuery has `$(window).width()` with better browser compatibility than `window.innerWidth`